# Django. Model. how to create request and get value with two conditions

Tags: django, django-models

I have django Model below

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Bid")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lot = models.ForeignKey(Lot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

how can I get username from field 'user' with two conditions: known 'lot' and max 'bid' value. Try explain, I know 'lot' and I need to get 'user' for this 'lot', where value of 'bid' is max.

Comment: So `lot` is given?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the largest `Bid` for a given `lot` with:

```
Bid.objects.filter(lot=lot).latest('bid')
```

This will return a `Bid` object with the largest `bid` for that `lot`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).